# Sending authenticated requests to GitHub API from authorized Auth0 app user

Tags: angularjs, github, oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I am having a very difficult time getting authenticated API requests to GitHub to work. I have created an authorized application in GitHub and connected it to my Auth0 account. I have no problems getting a user signed in using their GitHub account but once they are signed in I cannot make authenticated requests to the GitHub API (I am trying to set a GitHub webhook in one of the user's GitHub repos). All my requests are rejected for having incorrect credentials.

I have the JWT issued by Auth0 being sent along in each request to the GitHub API endpoint but it appears as though this is not sufficient. The Auth0 profile that comes back from my user seems to have an access_token in it, but sending this along does not work either.

Here is what my Auth0 login code looks like (using the Angular API):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'auth', 'store', '$location',
    function ($scope, $http, auth, store, $location) {
      $scope.login = function () {
        auth.signin({
            authParams: {
               responseType: 'token' // I think this is the default but just in case
            }
        }, function (profile, token) {
            // Success callback
            store.set('profile', profile);
            store.set('token', token);
            $location.path('/');
        }, function () {
            // Error callback
            console.debug("error logging in");
        });
      };
}]);
```

This works fine. They authorize the GitHub application tied to my organization's Auth0 account with its requested permissions without issue and land back in my application and I then have access to an Auth0 profile tied to their GitHub account, but then if I try and make an authenticated request to the GitHub API on their behalf:

```
var username = auth.nickname;
var repo = "some_user.github.io"; // todo: get repo from setup process
var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + username + "/" + repo + "/hooks/";
var conf = {
    name: "web",
    active: true,
    config: {
        "url": "https://webtask.it.auth0.com/api/run/wt-my-container_com-0/echo?webtask_no_cache=1",
        "content_type": "json"
    }
};
$http.post(url, conf).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log("post successful:");
    console.log(status);
    console.log(data);
});
```

... GitHub rejects the request, either saying the request resource doesn't exist (to prevent private data leakage) or that I supplied bad credentials, depending on different variables (if I try supplying the "access_token" field provided in their Auth0 profile as a query param or supply my Auth0 application's client secret, etc).

I have scoured the documentation of both Auth0 and GitHub trying to figure out what the correct procedure is (for example, do I need to implement the whole OAuth2 token flow myself? it seems like Auth0 should be doing that for me) but nothing I have tried so far works, and nothing on Google has pointed me in the right direction. I have tried a number of other methods of doing this without success but I don't want to make this post too much longer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. There were two problems: one, a trailing slash had crept in on the end of my API call to the GitHub endpoint, which evidently breaks something and causes GitHub to reject the request, and second, I had set things up to send along the Authorization header with every request as per the Auth0 guide here: https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/angularjs, specifically this part:

```
myApp.config(function (authProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {
  // ...

  // We're annotating this function so that the `store` is injected correctly when this file is minified
  jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = ['store', function(store) {
    // Return the saved token
    return store.get('token');
  }];

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
  // ...
});
```

But GitHub does not like that since it does not contain the token it is expecting and will reject the request if it sees it. Once I removed the trailing slash and removed the above code, everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this gitHub page](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/). It is something like this with angular:

```
//'common' will add the headder to every request.
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token YOUR_TOKEN;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that without success using the token provided by Auth0 upon successfully logging in. The POST request has the correct Authorization header with the correct token but it is still rejected. I have also tried the access_token provided in the Auth0 user's profile as well as the token provided by this Auth0 API call:

    auth.getToken({
        api: 'github'
    }).then(function(result) { //... }